# How to change CSS styles for radio buttons generated in loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the color of the radio button when the radio button is selected.

I know the default way is to use `:checked` but that doesn't seem to work. Curiously, `:hover` seems to work but I can't seem to style the radio button when checked.

The one complicating factor is that I needed to create the radio buttons in a JavaScript for loop, rather than one-by-one in my HTML file.

I have tried using `input[type=radio]` or variants of that but to no avail.

Sorry, I'm kinda new at this and am trying to follow a tutorial :(

```
function buildQuiz(){

  // Store the HTML output
  const output = [];

  // Loop to iterate through each question...
  myQuestions.forEach(
    (currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {
      // Store the list of answer choices
      const answers = [];
      // Iterate through each answer in a question
      for(letter in currentQuestion.answerList){
        // Add HTML radio buttons for each answer choice
        answers.push(
          `<label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" value="${letter}">
            ${currentQuestion.answerList[letter][0]}
          </label>`
        );
      }

      // Add this question and its answers to the output
      output.push(
        `<div class="slide">
          <div class="question"> ${currentQuestion.question} </div>
          <div class="answers"> ${answers.join('')} </div>
        </div>`
      );
    }
  );
  // Combine our output list into one string of HTML and put it on the page
  quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join('');
}
```

Comment: if you're using jQuery to set them programatically, use a selector that targets an element available on document load. The most logical target would be the parent that the radio buttons are appended to. jQuery can't target elements added after page load

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure ... are you looking for something like this?

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  $('form').append(`
    <input type="radio" name="choose" value="${i}">
  `)
}
```

```css
input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;

  border: 2px solid #999;
  transition: 0.2s all linear;
  outline: none;
  margin-right: 5px;

  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}

input:checked {
  border: 6px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form></form>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and thank you for the help!

That's pretty close to what I imagined. However, in addition to the radio button itself changing color, I also want the text for the radio button to change color when selected.

Comment: @Archlefirth It's no problem also. You can delete CSS style for `input:checked` and change it programatically, with JS, along with label text.